# How to have custom fb,google login button Android?

Tags: android, xml

I'm new to designing. I want to have custom sign in buttons (Facebook, & Google) with round corners like Canva in Android, meeting the required design guidelines of both of them. How can I achieve it?[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Android Studio, you can add the line

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fb_icon"
```

to your button code that will reference a custom drawable object with your desired shape.

Comment: The main concern is following the fb/Google design guidelines. Can I have a regular textview with the drawable instead of their default buttons?